# Delete element from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

using a drop-down list that's populated from database fields, i need to select an option and then delete that from the database. i'm trying to do this by sending the form to a process php page where i pull in the select option from the post array and then delete it from the database and return to the index page.
 having issues with getting the array variable from the post array. can anyone help with some code on how to get the variable and then delete the mysql title

```
<form method="post" action="deleteReview_process.php">

<select name="title">

    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
            $movieTitle = $row['title'];
    ?>

<option><?php echo $movieTitle; ?></option>

    <?php } ?>

</select>

<input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" value="delete" />
```

---- and the process page ---

```
include 'inc/db.inc.php';

if($_POST['delete']) {

    $title = $_POST['title'][$movieTitle];   <------ NOT WORKING


    $sql = "DELETE" . $title . "FROM pageTitle";
    mysql_query($sql, $conn)
        or die("couldn't execute query");


    header("Location: http://localhost/cms/index.php");

    }
    else
    {

    header("Location: http://localhost/cms/deleteReview.php");

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `SELECT` element is named "title," it will be represented as `$_POST["title"]` when it arrives to the backend script:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
```

Also, your query needs to be corrected:

```
$sql = "DELETE" . $title . "FROM pageTitle";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tableName WHERE title = '{$title}'";
```

Comment: thanks, and how about the sql statement... how to gett that right??

Answer (score 0):

`$title` is going to be in `$_POST['title']` ie. `$title = $_POST['title']`